# chrome.extension.getViews() and Extension Options page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

If I open a new tab and navigate to `chrome-extension://{ext_id}/options.html` by typing directly into the address bar the page shows up in the list when I do

```
chrome.extension.getViews({'tab'})
```

This is the expected behaviour.

If I [right click] on my extensions "browser_action" action and select "Options" this brings up a new tab with `chrome-extension://{ext_id}/options.html` as the URL and it shows up in the list when I do

```
chrome.extension.getViews({'tab'})
```

Again, this is the expected behavior.

If I click a link on my extensions popup, that navigates to the options page, this opens up a new tab and navigates me to `chrome-extension://{ext_id}/options.html`. This is the expected behavior.

**BUT**, there is always a but, for some reason this page does **NOT** show up in

```
chrome.extension.getViews({'tab'})
```

Even though it is obviously within the context and protocol of the extension. I just don't know what the difference between the FIRST and the LAST scenario is. If anything I would expect the first scenario to fail since the user is manually navigating there, rather than a extensions own popup navigating to the extensions own options page.

I have tried using both

```
<a href="options.html" target="_blank"> 
/* and */
<a id="options" target="_blank">
<script>
    document.getElementById('options').href = chrome.extension.getURL('options.html');
</script>
/* This correctly sets the href as chrome-extension://{ext_id}/options.html */
```

but again the same problem. The extension still runs all its Javascript correctly. I still am able to use `chrome.extension` functionality correctly. Just the page is not showing up within `getViews`. I suspect it is a Sandboxing issue, but I can't understand it working for all other situations expect one.

Does anyone know how to either get it to work correctly? or open up the page in a different manner so it will work?

PS: I do not wish to open up the options page within the popup window. I have tested this, and it STILL does not list the page within the getViews but I presume this is because it is no longer a 'tab' but a 'popup'.. But again, its not the behavior I wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it looks like a bug and feels like a bug, then it is probably a bug. In the future, if you think that you're experiencing a bug, don't hesitate reporting it on Chromium's bug tracker at http://crbug.com/new.

I have reported your bug as https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=341459.

A work-around to get your extension page opened from the popup window to show up in `chrome.extensions.getView({type: 'tab'})` is to open the tab using [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-create):

```
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: 'options.html'
});
```

Comment: I am just experimenting with this technique this very minute when i seen on the documentation you do **not** need the tabs permission to use most of the functionality.

Comment: This worked. Not quite as elegant as using href but I can live with it. Also, thank you for making the issue on chromium.